# Find the user which is trying to sign-in or sign-up via cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using the devise gem, I want to be able to find the user that just signed-up or that is trying to sign-in via cookie and pass some other code after that!

Comment: by finding, what do you mean ? I guess since the user has not signed in yet, there is no session created and you can't really refer to him in your code. Yet he is now in database. you can still parse new users which account is not yet confirmed..

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Maxence... no the user is not signed-in yet so there is no session. What I'm after is: I want to be able to find the user that just signed-up and pass some other code after that! Similar to the current_user helper, but wihtout signing-in!

Comment: then you have to tweak devise registration controller to add more action to the newly created user. You have to generate Devise controllers in your application first if not already done. Another solution, if you just have to show a specific message in an HTML page, just define the after signup up link as per advised here : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign_in,-sign_out,-and-or-sign_up

Comment: I have all devise controllers set up, please check updated description for more details.

Comment: where is located the above bit of code you display ? please give file name and path

Comment: The above code is located in the model user.rb

Comment: well if you have controllers for devise, then you have a `users` folder in your controllers folder. In this `users` folder, one controller is called `registrations_controller.rb`. You can tweak it and catch the new user there. Also if the above bit of code is in your model file, it should apply to every new user. You should not just use `current_user` in your model (I am not great at coding ruby inside the model, so I cannot help further, but using `self` instead of `current_user` may do the trick )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In registrations and sessions controller under the method `create` I placed the following code:

```
cookies[:email] = {:value => params[:user][:email],
                    :domain => :all, :expires => 1.hour.from_now}
```

and after that I can find the `current_user` with the following method:

```
def current_user
  if cookies["email"].present?
    User.find_by_email(cookies["email"])
  end
end
```